# mysql left join empty varchar both side (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, string, join

I have to join two table with VARCHAR columns. Both of this columns contain multiple empty values but i want to ignore them.
The inner join query works fine :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 t1 
JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.col = t2.col and t1.col <> ''
```

But what i need is a left join :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.col = t2.col and t1.col <> ''
```

And this one i taking 20-30 seconde to execute... i think it's doing the join operation before it cuts the empty values. I can't found a solution to force  the <> '' condition first.

Same request without the condition take the same execution time :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.col = t2.col
```

but return 50 000 000 vs 150 000 for the first one.

```
tbl1 :
'OOOOA' 'fieldtbl1'
'OOOOB' 'fieldtbl1'
'OOOOC' 'fieldtbl1'
'OOOOD' 'fieldtbl1'
''      'fieldtbl1'

tbl2 :
'OOOOA' 'fieldtbl2'
'OOOOB' 'fieldtbl2'
'OOOOC' 'fieldtbl2'
''      'fieldtbl2'

expected result :
'OOOOA' 'fieldtbl1'   'fieldtbl2'
'OOOOB' 'fieldtbl1'   'fieldtbl2'
'OOOOC' 'fieldtbl1'   'fieldtbl2'
'OOOOD' 'fieldtbl1'   null
''      'fieldtbl1'   null
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Since your query already specifies join condition `t1.col = t2.col`, and the where clause is `T1.col <> ''`, this already implies that `t2.col <> ''` so just remove it from the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my question but i still have my execution time problem

Answer (score 0):

As @Matteo Tassinari said, Your condition are failure of together. This is why it takes a long time to process, You need to delete one of them:

```
 t2.col <> ''
```

or

```
T1.col <> ''
```

Because you used `t1.col = t2.col` in `where` clause (`ON`).

In fact your full code should be some thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.col = t2.col and t2.col <> '',
```

Comment: Thanks, i only need the first clause. But it does not impact the execution time. Still 0.8s for inner join and 20-30s for the left join. with a select count(*).

Comment: Can you use `UNION` ? I think it is more better for your query...!

Comment: I don't think so sinc i need both columns from tbl1 and tbl2. And in my real request i have several join but this one is making the request very slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

This is a *very* strange query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     tbl2 t2
     ON t1.col = t2.col and t1.col <> '';
```

It would often do exactly the same thing as:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     tbl2 t2
     ON t1.col = t2.col;
```

The reason is that for a `LEFT JOIN`, rows in the first table are kept, regardless of whether the `ON` condition is true or false.  This even applies to conditions on the first table.

As for performance, your queries will run better if you have indexes on `tbl1(col)`, and `tbl2(col)`.

Perhaps you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention that both column were indexed. I'll update my question.

Comment: I edited the question (in real condition both table have lots of column). To be clear, i have the results i expect but the query is  slow.